# Read json file in batch file and extract values

Tags: batch-file

I have a config file "config.json"...

```
{
   host: "abc",
   port: "59300"
}
```

I want to extract the values of host & port and feed it to a bat file, the contents of which read,

```
@echo off
cmd /c "cd /d %ZOWE_HOME%\zlux-app-server\bin && nodeServer.bat --allowInvalidTLSProxy=true -h %host% -P %port% -p 9999"
```

How to accomplish this in a single .bat file?

Comment: Don't use internal batch file comnands to try to read and parse `json` data. Use, or at least get help from, PowerShell, which has native methods of doing that.

Answer (score -1):

Insert these lines between your two lines

```
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2delims=:, " %%b IN ("u:\your files\q76447808.txt") DO (
 FOR %%e IN (host port) DO IF "%%e"=="%%b" SET "%%b=%%~c"
)

ECHO host=%host% port=%port%
```

Notes : 
It's SOP to follow with a `setlocal` line to keep the environment clean
The first three lines of this code may be compated to one. I left it at 3 for clarity
The `ECHO` line is simply to show the results
You would need to understand the [delayed expansion trap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2128947) if you want to further compact the code (which is not necessary in any case)

Comment: Just to make you aware Magoo, that in these confguration files, value names can, and often are, repeated. Also, very often, _(really should be)_, both key pairs, are doublequoted too.

Comment: @compo : Can only go on the example posted.